# Prove Green Theorem using Gauss Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

> **Problem.** Consider the General Stokes Theorem and $M$ a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with boundary orientable.
>
> (a) Prove the Green Theorem
>   $$\int_{M}(g_{x} - f_{y})dxdy = \int_{\partial M} fdx + gdy$$
>   from Stokes Theorem.
>
> (b) Prove the Gauss Theorem
>   $$\int_{M}\mathrm{div}FdV = \int_{\partial M}\langle F, n \rangle dA$$
>   from Stokes Theorem.
>
> (c) Use Gauss Theorem to prove the Green Theorem.

**My attempt**

(a) Take the $1$-form $\omega = fdx + gdy$. Then

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\partial M}fdx + gdy &=& \int_{\partial M}\omega\\
&=& \int_{M}d\omega\\
&=& \int_{M}d(fdx + gdy)\\
&=& \int_{M}d(f)\wedge dx + d(g)\wedge dy\\
&=& \int_{M}(f_{x}dx + f_{y}dy)\wedge dx + (g_{x}dx + d_{y}dy)\wedge dy\\
&=& \int_{M}f_{y}dy\wedge dx + g_{x}dx\wedge dy\\
&=& \int_{M}g_{x}dx\wedge dy - f_{y}dx\wedge dy\\
&=& \int_{M}(g_{x}-f_{y})dxdy.
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

(b) Consider $n = 3$ (the general case works with the same idea). Take $\omega = F_{1}dy\wedge dz + F_{2}dz\wedge dx + F_{3}dx\wedge dy$.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\partial M}\langle F,n \rangle dA &=& \int_{\partial M}F_{1}n_{1} + F_{2}n_{2} + F_{3}n_{3}\\
&=& \int_{\partial M}F_{1}(n_{1}dA) + F_{2}(n_{2}dA) + F_{3}(n_{3}dA)\\
&=& \int_{\partial M}F_{1}dy\wedge dz + F_{2}dz\wedge dx + F_{3}dx\wedge dy\\
&=& \int_{\partial M}\omega\\
&=& \int_{M}d\omega\\
&=& \int_{M}d(F_{1}dy\wedge dz + F_{2}dz\wedge dx + F_{3}dx\wedge dy)\\
&=& \int_{M}d(F_{1})\wedge dy\wedge dz + d(F_{2})\wedge dz\wedge dx + d(F_{3})\wedge dx\wedge dy\\
&=& \int_{M}F_{1}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz + F_{2}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz + F_{3}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\\
&=& \int_{M}\mathrm{div}FdV.
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

(c) I tried to use *Gauss* $\to$ *Stokes* (in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$) $\to$ *Green*, but I couldnt prove (probably dont work). Can someone help me?

The items (a) and (b) I wrote a sketch of the prove (without the details) because I believe that this idea is correct, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If this is "without the details," I wonder what details you think are lacking. :)  To do (c), you need to do everything in $\Bbb R^2$, not $\Bbb R^3$. Think about rotating the vector field by $\pi/2$ to turn the outward normal into the tangent to the curve.